# Implementing active/passive cluster: how to use Oracle for my distributed lock?

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, distributed-computing

I am trying to implement an active/passive cluster of servers. I've done this kind of thing before using SQL Server's [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

I could turn to Oracle's [`DBMS_LOCK`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lock.htm), but for various (dumb IMO) reasons the DBAs will not grant access to do this.

I tried resorting to executing the SQL `LOCK TABLE x IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` from my C# followed by a `Thread.Sleep()` inside a transaction; this did not block the other server when that server executed the same code. I had expected it to do so.

Do I need to do something else, or is there another method to use Oracle in a blocking way for my application lock?

I know I could loop reading a lock value looking for a change, but I'd rather not simulate a lock with polling.

Comment: You need a way for client to to acquire an exclusive right to perform a particular transaction?  Does this exclusive right commit at any point (other than at the very end)?

Comment: Yes, and the commit is at the end of the transaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your clients do not need to commit until the very end, this should be easy.

Create a table with one column and one record in it.  E.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE my_lock ( dummy varchar2(1) );
INSERT INTO my_lock VALUES ( 'X' );
COMMIT;
```

Have each transaction do this before attempting to start:

```
SELECT * FROM my_lock FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
```

If that succeeds, execute the transaction.  If it fails, wait and try again (or raise an error or whatever you want).

If you don't want to loop in the client, you can instead:

```
SELECT * FROM my_lock FOR UPDATE;
```

This will cause would-be transactions to pause until they can get the exclusive lock they need to begin, rather than giving them an error.

There are lots of ways to make that more interesting and robust, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: By the way the "security model" description of `DBMS_LOCK` talks about a way to manage the risks associated with granting access to `DBMS_LOCK`.  (And the risks exist -- it's not stupid).  Maybe you can review them and see if they would satisfy your DBAs.  See: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lock.htm#ARPLS66763

Comment: Thanks for the education. I knew there were some potential risks but not what they were exactly. I thought it would be fairly innocuous for a single-tenant database where my cluster is the only thing doing locking like this.

Comment: You're rght.. it's probably OK.  But most DBA's I know aren't satisfied by "probably ok".  )